# Authentication Failed when connecting to Imap server

Tags: c#, authentication, connection, imap

When I'm connecting to imap.gmail.com, the server is connected. But, the authentication is failed due to following error

**Server returned:CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT LITERAL+ IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE**

Any Idea plz???

Comment: I'm waiting!!! Still no response from anybody!!!!!!!!

Comment: Try updating your question to add things such as how you are connecting, what libraries are you using, what classes are you using, what type of exception are you getting and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail changed it's IMAP implementation, and several client libraries stopped working.

Now just after login GMail sends its **CAPABILITY** list, which causes some client to break.